# Renaming the "Customer Support" tooltip in Chatter Answers

Tags: community, label, chatter-answers

Implementing Chatter Answers in a community, we noticed the hover text over the microphone next to a Question or Answer by an internal user was "Customer Support". In this case, the support is supposed to be informal and our client wanted to change the value.

[image: Customer Support Tooltip]

I located the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=questions_portal_setup.htm&language=en_US) around changing this, but noticed that my changes didn't seem to propagate.

> You can rename Customer Support on your zones’ user interface. For example, you can change “Customer Support” to “Acme Support.” Just edit the Customer Support label on the Question object.

What I found strange was that if I opened up another browser, the internal "Questions" tab showed my new value. Once I shift-refreshed enough times in the original browser (who knows if that did anything), the new value came up in the internal "Questions" tab, but it has yet to take effect in the Community after a night (there are only a handful of fake test questions in there).

I had a similar experience in the sandbox, but after switching values in the label a few teams it seemed to just "work". Didn't have the same experience in production. Are the labels somehow caching?